# Convert datetime string to date/time: OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice, date-time

Format of text string: "05/04/2017 04:35 PM CEST"
Desired value: 5/04/2017 10:35 AM

Or "07/15/2017 01:05 AM CEST"
to 07/14/2017 7:35 PM

Possible?

OO 4.1.3 on Win7 Home Premium SP1

Comment: Are you looking for a CALC formula? I guess not (or at least not easy). I'm a macro guy, I would use StarBasic or Python to "get what I want": is this an option (for you)?

Comment: @ngulam I would prefer a CALC formula, as that is where the list containing these entries was written up. I have never been exposed to the other ways you mentioned.

Comment: I currently only have LibreOffice installed - here I would use (a) strip the "CEST" [`=LEFT(a1); LENGTH(a1) - 5`], (b) user `DATEVALUE` function to convert text to number [internal date/time counter], then (c) add the time difference. Finally add the desired formatting. Apply the formulae as "steps" in helper cells [columns; besides the original values], to see what is working.